# How to remove minute in TIME Data Type in SQL/Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, time, simple-form

I've got a form for selecting TIME. I'm using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [Jquery Timepicker](https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-timepicker-rails). How do I remove the minute field of the form. So I have two fields for the :mondayopen parameter showing up. One is the hour and the other is the minute. How can I remove the minute.

Here's how it currently looks:
[image]

**My Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @store], :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
    </br>
    <%= f.input :mondayopen, :label => 'Monday Open Time', :input_html => { :class => 'mondayo' } %>        
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary', style: 'margin-left: 40px;'  %><%= link_to 'Your Store', user_store_path(current_user, @store), :class => 'btn btn-inverse edit_store_button_path' %>
<% end %>
```

```
<script>
    $('.mondayo').timepicker({ 'step': 15 });
    $('.mondayc').timepicker({ 'step': 15 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `mondayopen` field as `time` type field SimpleForm creates `time_select` for you but you don't need it as you are using jquery timepicker plugin. So you can just redefine it like this:

```
<%= f.input :mondayopen, :as => :string, :label => 'Monday Open Time', :input_html => { :class => 'mondayo' } %>
```